# Add a vector to every column of a matrix, using Scala Breeze

Tags: scala, matrix, scala-breeze

I have a matrix M of (L x N) rank and I want to add the same vector v of length L to every column of the matrix. Is there a way do this please, using Scala Breeze?

I tried:

```
val H = DenseMatrix.zeros(L,N)
  for (j <- 0 to L) {
  H (::,j) = M(::,j) + v
}
```

but this doesn't really fit Scala's immutability as H is then already defined and therefore gives a reassignment to val error. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a vector to all columns of a matrix, you don't need to loop through columns; you can use the column broadcasting feature, for your example:

```
H(::,*) + v             // assume v is breeze dense vector
```

Should work.

---

```
import breeze.linalg._

val L = 3
val N = 2
val v = DenseVector(1.0,2.0,3.0)
val H = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](L, N)

val result = H(::,*) + v

//result: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double] = 1.0  1.0  
//                                            2.0  2.0  
//                                            3.0  3.0
```

Comment: But actually I am getting the following error: Error:(249, 42) could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpAdd.Impl2[breeze.linalg.BroadcastedColumns[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]],breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double],That]
    val H: BDM[Double] = sigmoid(M(::,*) + bias) // We want H to be N x L

Comment: I'm pretty new to Breeze and that's an error which doesn't mean much. Am I missing an import statement, for example?

Comment: Check if these two are true: 1) the type of `bias` is DenseVector; 2) the length of `bias` is equal to `M.rows`;

Comment: OK, ignore me, I realise I didn't convert b (or v in your example) to a vector, it was still in matrix format. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Psidom This is failing in breeze 1.0: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Vectors must have same length: x.length == y.length (2 != 3)`. My code: `val v = DenseVector(1.0, 2.0)`, `val m1 = DenseMatrix((2.0, 3.0), (5.0, 6.0), (8.0, 9.0))`, `m1(::, *) + v`